# Functional languages 'Under the hood'

Tags: functional-programming

This answer is probably obvious to most but not to me as I am struggling to find an answer.

I have been making heavy use of functional operators in Java 11 as I like the declarative nature of streams and operations.

Just for curiosities sake... I wanted to understand how the various methods

```
Stream.map(), Stream.reduce(), Stream.filter(), Stream.collect()
```

Work under the hood?

From [this](https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-java-util-stream-collector-basics-tutorial-with-examples/)page, the Java implementation requires mutable (an accumulator) state at some point to be able to create a result.

Is this true of all functional languages eg does Haskell handle all mutable operations under the hood so that the user can make use of immutable results?

Comment: Yes. Every language implementation that runs on a real-world computer relies on mutable memory operations under the hood.

Comment: It depends on how deep you look under the hood. If you have the single linked `List` type for instance and lazy evaluation, you can get stream-like behavior at the term level. Here is an [example in Javascript](https://repl.it/@scriptum/JuvenileWhimsicalWatchdog). Please note that in this example the result is stored in a mutable array, but I could have used an immutable `List` instead. However, the way the non-strict semantics is mimicked (`ThunkProxy`) relies on mutability. So ultimately things get impure.